# Delete from 'table2' where column = 'value' IF column in 'table1' = 'value'

Tags: mysql, where-clause, sql-delete

I am trying to execute a MySQL query to delete rows from 'table2' where column = 'value' IF column in 'table1' = 'value'

I have 2 tables...

Table 1 is called 'accounts'
Table 2 is called 'inventoryitems'

The column in question for 'accounts' is called 'banned'
The column in question for 'inventoryitems' is called 'itemid'

I would like to DELETE FROM `inventoryitems` WHERE `itemid` = `2340000`
IF...
the column `banned` in `accounts` has a value of `1`

**Extra Information:**

You can join the table `accounts` to `inventoryitems` by a 3rd table called `characters`.

Table `accounts` has columns: `id` (primary key) and `banned`.

Table `characters` has columns: `characterid` and `accountid` (`accountid` links to `id` in table `accounts`).

Table `inventoryitems` has columns `itemid` and `characterid` (`characterid` links to `characterid` in table `characters`)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do they have a column where they can be joined? I assume yes, I just need the name.

Comment: They do not have a column that can be joined... Unless you get the column `id` from `accounts` and then get the `characterid` where `accountid` matches the `id` from `acccounts` and then find the `characterid` that matches `characterid` in `inventoryitems`... That has probably just confused you now...

Comment: If they cannot be joined on a column, how do you know which item pertains to which account?  They have to be related SOMEHOW, otherwise you're randomly deleting and hoping for the best.  Having this information, I've deleted my answer.  I was under the impression that there was a common column to join on.

Comment: Nick is correct, they need to be joined somehow, even if through a third table.

Comment: Yes they are related via another table called `characters`... I'll try to explain more clearly and include some more columns that will help relate them... The table `accounts` has columns `id` and `banned`. The table `inventoryitems` has columns `characterid` and `itemid`. The table `characters` has columns `accountid` (which is joined to `accounts` table column `id`) and `characterid`.

Comment: I think I made it slightly more clear in the main question now, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE FROM inventoryitems
WHERE characterid IN
    (SELECT id
     from characters
     WHERE accountid IN 
        (SELECT id 
         from accounts
         WHERE banned = '1'
        )
    ) 
  AND itemid = '2340000';`

Answer (score 0):

The following query is using a `INNER JOIN` to remove one row from table `inventoryitems`:

```
DELETE i FROM inventoryitems i  
INNER JOIN characters c ON i.characterid = c.characterid 
INNER JOIN accounts a ON c.accountid = a.id 
WHERE i.itemid = 2340000 && a.banned = 1;
```

Comment: I need to only delete rows from `inventoryitems` where `itemid` is a value of `2340000`. I don't see that value in your answer. Sorry if I wasn't very clear.

Comment: Hmmm I must not have noticed your edit, sorry. I just tried your script but got "Unknown column 'item.itemid' in 'where clause'"

There is no itemid column in the accounts table.

Comment: @MattPrince - I don't get it the above should work just fine (tried it with the same table structure that you have) and I think it should be more efficient then doing two subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, since I gathered from your comment that they can be probably joined this way.

```
DELETE FROM inventoryitems WHERE characterid IN
(SELECT characterid from characters WHERE accountid IN
(SELECT id from accounts WHERE banned = 1))
AND itemid = '2340000';
```

Comment: Okay, this seemed to delete 1 row. Not sure which one (this is a backup of my live database I am testing this query on of course). There are a lot of other rows that do meet the criteria though. Do I just need to keep running this same script to delete them all?

Comment: The second time I ran it, returned no results... So I have no idea what this deleted lol...

Comment: I think I made it a bit more clear again in the main question now.

Comment: Edited my answer, I think I have an idea how to join them now.

Comment: Actually this is still incorrect! This query deleted all rows in `inventoryitems` where `itemid` was '2340000'. It didn't seem to check if the banned column was 1! Sorry to disappoint... But thank you for your help!!

Comment: Very close, you helped a lot though. Correct script is `DELETE FROM inventoryitems WHERE characterid IN (SELECT id from characters WHERE accountid IN (SELECT id from accounts WHERE banned = '1' ) ) AND itemid = '2340000';`

Comment: Oh, it wasn't an integer then? Thought it was. Oh well.

Comment: It was an integer... it was the 'SELECT characterid from characters' needed to be 'SELECT id from characters'